# How do I get URL from WP_HTTP object?

Tags: php, http-api

I'm using wp_remote_post:

```
    $test = wp_remote_post($environment_url, $args2 );
    $test2 = $test['http_response'];
```

So what I want to do is get the value of URL but I believe the object is protected so having difficulty getting to it.

The answer may be here

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_requests_response/

But I need help finding it.

Here is the output of $test2:

```
WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object
(
[response:protected] => Requests_Response Object
    (
        [body] => ...
        [raw] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                 Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store

        [headers] => Requests_Response_Headers Object
            (
                [data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [cache-control] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => no-cache, no-store
                            )
                            ...
                    )

            )

        [status_code] => 200
        [protocol_version] => 1.1
        [success] => 1
        [redirects] => 1
        [url] => https://www.example.com
        [history] => Array
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're after here, but you can try to get the HTTP response object from the  `WP_HTTP_Requests_Response::get_response_object()` method.

Here's an example to retrieve the url:

```
if( 
       ! is_wp_error( $test )
    && isset( $test['http_response'] ) 
    && $test['http_response'] instanceof \WP_HTTP_Requests_Response 
    && method_exists( $test['http_response'], 'get_response_object' )
)
    echo $test['http_response']->get_response_object()->url;
```

Comment: Hi that is EXACTLY what I needed. Now I realise that my PHP skills aren't as good as yours - so can you explain how I could have figured this out myself? The bit which mainly confuses me at this point is 'instanceof \WP...' - why does it have a \ and what does instanceof refer to? Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. I just skimmed through the class to find something useful that you could use. That's when I spotted the `get_response_object()` method. If we use namespace, we need to reference the WordPress classes with \ in front as they live in the global scope. You can skip the \ if you don't use your own namespaces. Since we are going to use the get_response_object() method, I check if we have an object instance from that relevant class. Another idea would be to get the url from filters, e.g. `http_request_args` @ravravrav

Comment: Hi it took me 2 days to find this answer so really appreciate it from you. Based on the above I think it's OOP which is my weak point because I didn't fully understand the class / method concept. Do you think that's what I should focus on or anything else as well?

Comment: Yes I think it could help here to look into OOP, at least I'm still trying to learn it, even though there are some that say [it's bad](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/08/object-oriented-programming-is-exceptionally-bad/) for "code health" ;-)re